# Rewrite JsonNode object to new one with new name of attributes and bypassing some nodes

Tags: java, json, algorithm, jackson

Is it possible to rewrite (or update) `JsonNode` to new one with new attributes names and bypassing some nodes?

Let's suppose I have Json like:

```
{
   "reservations":[
      {
         "id":"1318504",
         "deposit":720,
         "rooms":[
            {
               "name":"room1",
               "id":"28902"
            },
            {
               "name":"room2",
               "id":"28906"
            }
         ],
         "customers":[
            {
               "id":3,
               "country":"UK",
               "firstName":"John"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"1318501",
         "deposit":68,
         "rooms":[
            {
               "name":"room3",
               "id":"28860"
            },
            {
               "name":"room4",
               "id":"28886"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I read it as

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode node = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(new File("path to json file"));
```

And now I would like to have function like `JsonNode rewrite(List<String> ignoreData)` and if I call it with arguments `ignoreData = ["customers"]` then I will have new `JsonNode` which will look like:

```
{
   "reservations":[
      {
         "reservations.id":"1318504",
         "reservations.deposit":720,
         "reservations.rooms":[
            {
               "reservations.rooms.name":"room1",
               "reservations.rooms.id":"28902"
            },
            {
               "reservations.rooms.name":"room2",
               "reservations.rooms.id":"28906"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "reservations.id":"1318501",
         "reservations.deposit":68,
         "reservations.rooms":[
            {
               "reservations.rooms.name":"room3",
               "reservations.rooms.id":"28860"
            },
            {
               "reservations.rooms.name":"room4",
               "reservations.rooms.id":"28886"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Is it possible with jackson library? Pseudo-code is ok for me.

Comment: So your "id" becomes "reservations.id" , deposit becomes reservations.deposit ? like this you want? or just remove the customer node ?

Comment: I dont see any point of doing that

Comment: Any of this functionality is possible? Is is possible to rename attributes like in example? Is it possible to remove node with given name?

Comment: gave my answer, Please check. hope it helps

Comment: And what about renaming nodes? Is it possible?

Comment: I renamed one of the nodes. The "id" node. Please check. Rest all are trivial

Comment: Ok I see. Is it possible to convert it to byte[] or String and use in other API (np. jackson) ?

Comment: Convert what to byte array or string?  The result ? Ofcourse. jsonContext.jsonString() is the JSON string. You can feed it to object mapper.

Comment: Ok and one question more - is it possible to rename all attributes in any loop or something like that?

Comment: Yes possible. You just need a list or map of oldKeys and newKeys and loop through the collection and call: jsonContext.renameKey("$.reservations[*]",oldKey,newKey);

Comment: mosiek, does this answer all your questions?

Comment: But how can I change ```name``` of ```id``` in rooms? I think if I call ```jsonContext.renameKey("$.reservations[*]","id","reservations.rooms.id");``` will not work...

Comment: It's simple bro. Just use : `jsonContext.renameKey("$.reservations[*].rooms[*]","id","reservations.rooms.id");` Are u getting the pattern here? You can keep on going to any nesting level. But while replacing to avoid errors,make sure to replace the deepest level first

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty you helped me very much. But I have one question more. How can I remove nested object from my json if I have only name of this nested object? So in my case, let's suppose that I have only name "rooms" but reservation is unknown. How can I now build json path?

Comment: mosiek, it's like XPath . You got to know the structure of the json. i.e path from root to that Node. Even when loading a JSON to an object using ObjectMapper , you know the structure of the JSON right? Just in the same way.

Comment: Unfortunately, the structure of JSON is unknown.

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty I know. I'm sorry. But JsonPath is something new for me and I am learning it now. But you still helped me a lot and I'm very grateful! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to remove/manipulate json nodes is by using JsonPath. It is a powerful tool to analyse, transform and selectively extract data out of Json documents.

It is the equivalent of Xpath used for XML documents.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code to remove 'customers' node and renaming the "id" under reservations. Similarly you can rename other fields too.:

```
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("src/main/resources/sample.json"), "UTF-8");
    DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.parse(content);
    jsonContext.delete("$.reservations[*].customers");
    jsonContext.renameKey("$.reservations[*]","id","reservations.id");
    System.out.println(jsonContext.jsonString());
```

Outputs:

```
{
   "reservations":[
      {
         "deposit":720,
         "rooms":[
            {
               "name":"room1",
               "id":"28902"
            },
            {
               "name":"room2",
               "id":"28906"
            }
         ],
         "reservations.id":"1318504"
      },
      {
         "deposit":68,
         "rooms":[
            {
               "name":"room3",
               "id":"28860"
            },
            {
               "name":"room4",
               "id":"28886"
            }
         ],
         "reservations.id":"1318501"
      }
   ]
}
```